# In awk how to keep backslash escape characters in printing?

Tags: awk

I read a line from a file, the line looks something like this :

```
"I am having \"fun\", and.."
```

but in awk, when I have it print out, it discarded or showing without the backslash character.  How do I keep it?  I used `printf("%s",..)`.

this awk program which would eventually return (by printing) the result and assigned it to a shell script variable but when the script variable showing no escape backslash.

Comment: Show us your complete awk command.

Comment: Did you actually check the direct output from `awk` or just the value from the shell variable? How did you check the variable value exactly?

Comment: There are many opportunities for either `awk` or `bash` to evaluate and thereby kill the `\"`. You will have to show us enough of the script to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: wrt input, showing us `something like this` is vastly less useful than `exactly this`. Awk does not discard backslashes. Show us a small script that reproduces just this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This example:

```
awk '1' <<<'I am having \"fun\", and..'
```

works for me. Are you sure that the shell doesn't expand the slashes? The following example will "remove" the slashes:

```
# Note the double quotes ------------>
awk '1' <<<"I am having \"fun\", and.."
```